# Converting a generic function to Kotlin fails

Tags: generics, lambda, kotlin

I'd like to rewrite some of my code to Kotlin. I pasted the working code first to show the origin.
I tried

The following is a working excerpt written in Java:

Function1.class (part of a framework):

```
public interface Function1<T1, R> {
    R call(T1 var1);
}
```

Authmanager.class:

```
public boolean isAuthed() {
    Boolean isAuthed = getWithAuthPolicyManager(
            authPolicyManager -> authPolicyManager.getBoolean(IS_AUTHED)
    );

    if (isAuthed != null) {
        return isAuthed;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public <T> T getWithAuthPolicyManager(@NonNull Function1<AuthManager, T> function) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(function);
    synchronized (AUTH_POLICY_LOCK) {
        try {
            openAuthPolicyManager();
            return function.call(authPolicyManager);
        } catch (OpenFailureException | EncryptionError e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error:", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            authPolicyManager.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

I would like to rewrite it to Kotlin but I cannot:
Authmanager.kt

```
fun isAuthed(): Boolean {
    val isAuthed =
        getWithAuthPolicyManager<Boolean>({
            authPolicyManager -> authPolicyManager.getBoolean(IS_AUTHED) 
        })
    return isAuthed ?: false
}

fun <T> getWithAuthPolicyManager(function: Function1<AuthManager, T>) : T? {
    synchronized (AUTH_POLICY_LOCK) {
        return try {
            openAuthPolicyManager();
            return function.call(authPolicyManager);
        } catch (OpenFailureException | EncryptionError e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error", e);
            null;
        } finally {
            authPolicyManager.close();
            null
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I just copy-pasted the Java code to the Kotlin class to automatically convert to Kotlin. However, the linter says:

```
Type mismatch.  
Required: Function1<AuthManager, Boolean>  
Found:    (AuthManager) -> Boolean!
```

to this line `getWithAuthPolicyManager<Boolean>({authPolicyManager -> authPolicyManager.getBoolean(IS_AUTHED)})` in `fun isAuthed()`.

Do you have any idea how this could be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second function is not converted at all, it still Java code. I used converter from [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org) and got the following code:

```
fun <T> getWithAuthPolicyManager(function : Function1<AuthManager, T>) : T? {
  synchronized (AUTH_POLICY_LOCK) {
    try
    {
      openAuthPolicyManager()
      return function.call(authPolicyManager)
    }
    catch (e : OpenFailureException) {
      LOGGER.error("Error", e)
      return null
    }
    catch (e : EncryptionError) {
      LOGGER.error("Error", e)
      return null
    }
    finally
    {
      authPolicyManager.close()
    }
  }
}
```

After light cleanup it should look like this:

```
inline fun <T> getWithAuthPolicyManager(function : (AuthManager) -> T?) : T? {
  synchronized (AUTH_POLICY_LOCK) {
    return try
    {
      openAuthPolicyManager()
      function(authPolicyManager)
    }
    catch (e : OpenFailureException) {
      LOGGER.error("Error", e)
      null
    }
    catch (e : EncryptionError) {
      LOGGER.error("Error", e)
      null
    }
    finally
    {
      authPolicyManager.close()
    }
  }
}
```

Please look into doing Kotlin tutorial if you can't tell Kotlin and Java function declarations apart.

Comment: Mea culpa, I copy-pasted the second Kotlin function wrongly to here. Thanks for spending your time on it, anyway! However, the problem still stands. Do you have any idea ? (function calls in getWithAuthPolicyManager() contains non-public-API calls, so I cannot make it an inline function)

Comment: Also changing `function : Function1<AuthManager, T>` to `function : (AuthManager) -> T?` solved the problem! Thanks!